# C Code doesn't work on Linux but Works on Mac

Tags: c, linux, macos

I've written and tested a small C program on Mac. However, when I compile using the make file on a linux machine I get an error that I'm not able to comprehend. Any help/pointer is appreciated.

```
    ssss@deas:a0$ make
    gcc -Wall -g   -c -o map.o map.c
    gcc -Wall -g   -c -o main.o main.c
    gcc   map.o main.o   -o map
    ssss@deas:a0$ ./map 
    insert 2 2
    Mapping  added successfully (old value was ).
    *** glibc detected *** ./map: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd7e0826b58 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x766d6)[0x7fd7e02ed6d6]
    ./map[0x400f5d]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fd7e029823d]
    ./map[0x4007b9]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:33 27911597                           /home/k/k7r7/cs317/a0/map
    00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:33 27911597                           /home/k/k7r7/cs317/a0/map
    00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:33 27911597                           /home/k/k7r7/cs317/a0/map
    00603000-00624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    7fd7e0061000-7fd7e0076000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 917688                     /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    7fd7e0076000-7fd7e0275000 ---p 00015000 08:01 917688                     /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    7fd7e0275000-7fd7e0276000 r--p 00014000 08:01 917688                     /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    7fd7e0276000-7fd7e0277000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 917688                     /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    7fd7e0277000-7fd7e03fe000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 917554                     /lib64/libc-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e03fe000-7fd7e05fd000 ---p 00187000 08:01 917554                     /lib64/libc-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e05fd000-7fd7e0601000 r--p 00186000 08:01 917554                     /lib64/libc-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e0601000-7fd7e0602000 rw-p 0018a000 08:01 917554                     /lib64/libc-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e0602000-7fd7e0607000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fd7e0607000-7fd7e0627000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 917547                     /lib64/ld-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e07e3000-7fd7e07e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fd7e0823000-7fd7e0827000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fd7e0827000-7fd7e0828000 r--p 00020000 08:01 917547                     /lib64/ld-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e0828000-7fd7e0829000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 917547                     /lib64/ld-2.14.1.so
    7fd7e0829000-7fd7e082a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fff9db94000-7fff9dbb5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
    7fff9dbff000-7fff9dc00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
    ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
    Aborted
```

How could this be possible?

Comment: Looks like you're freeing a pointer twice (or a null pointer).  You haven't given us much to go on.... Some questions: (a) what is the source code of the program?, (b) what are the versions of gcc on both machines?, (c) what external libraries, if any, are you using, and what are the versions on either machine?, (d) have you tried using valgrind or gdb? if so, what are their outputs?

Comment: It depends on the code.  valgrind could probably help.

Comment: Almost certainly double freeing memory.

Comment: *(total aside and not the problem at hand, but you certainly can call free on a null pointer, not sure if that's what you meant @cegfault)*

Comment: Sorry, @sixlettervariables, you are right; I mean invalid pointer.  Guess I'm kinda tired ;)

Comment: It was a pointer issue. Not dereferencing a pointer properly. I just found it odd how on my Mac I had no issues but on Linux it would bug me while running the program.

Answer (score 2):

it's bad code that dereferences a pointer which then cannot be freed.
if you wrote this, have a look at e-fence or valgrind.

Comment: So first run `valgrind ./map` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turned out gcc on Mac was not catching the pointer issue. But when running on Linux gcc it was, and causing this.